# Can I bind all underscore objects to native javascript prototypes?

Tags: javascript, ruby, backbone.js, binding, functional-programming

I'm fairly new to Javascript, but a little less new to Ruby. I love ruby's style of being able to call block functions directly from lists, i.e.

```
[1,2,3].each { |e| puts e }
```

It would feel very intuitive to me if I could do this in Javascript by doing something like `_.bind(_.each, Array.prototype, this)` and then calling it like this:

```
[1,2,3].each(function(e) { console.log(e) })
```

However, I know that it can be dangerous to try to pretend one language is another. I'm wondering if there's a way to make the binding work and if there are any reasons why it would be a very bad idea? Are there any existing methods of automatically applying all backbone functions to the Object, Array and Collection prototypes?

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: To be clear, I realize that the 'each' function exists in native Javascript, I'm using it as an example here. My question is on how to safely inject _ functions into native JS prototypes, not just the _.each function.

Comment: http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2008/12/rubys-each-for-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're targetting IE8 and below (and you should need a good reason to do) then you can do

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(e) { console.log(e) })
```

See [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

If for some reason you need to support IE8 (and you should need a good reason to do) then just stick with the underscore `_.each` method and use it directly. Backbone has a hard dependency on underscore in the first place so if you use Backbone you will have underscore available.

You can also just polyfill it, see the [mdn polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill).

Comment: To add some context to that, the app I am currently working on has about 1000 unique hits a day, and Google Analytics says we had 8 unique hits from IE8 over the last month. It's 2015, we don't need underscore to use basic ES5 functions anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my question is specifically about incorporating underscore functions into built-in JS objects.  It might be redundant with _.each, but this was just an example.

Comment: @user2130130 Ah right. I don't see an easy way of doing that for a general case since most underscore functions take the context as the first argument (e.g. `_.where(list, properties)`) so if you were to bind that to the Array prototype you'd have to curry it with `this` as the argument for `list` but you can't because there's no instance yet. As far as I can see there's no good way to do that but you could maybe go full enterprise and make an `ArrayFactory` that creates all your arrays for you and do `myArr.each = _.bind(_.each, myArr, myArr)` for each method you want to add.

Comment: But please don't do that. That would be a gateway drug to Java EE.